# Why is CSS object-position with percentages not centering my IMG

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to set a specific point on an image to always be in the center of the browser window or viewport, no matter what window size i am using. This would allow me to "highlight" something in a picture and make sure it's always in frame, no matter what device or screen size i'm using.
To achieve this i have tried everything using CSS properties object-position and object-fit. As an entry point, i have used the same system that Wordpress uses if you add images as backgrounds in a div inside a post. You can then set a "focal point" inside a visual editor and it basically gives you left and top percentages which it then uses with said CSS properties in the frontend.

However it seems that the CSS property object-position doesn't seem to center the set "focal point" of an image in the browser window. I can't find out why this is, it happens in every browser.

I have set up a little test below. The image that i have attached has a magenta cross which is exactly at 70% from left and 70% from the top. As of my understanding, by using the following code and setting the position to 70% and 70%, the cross should be centered in the viewport as soon as the white space on the right side of the cross allows it to. However, the cross seems to be way off center, even though it would be able to. You can test different values and see the cross move, so it's generally working. I have added blue lines along the image, so you can see when it starts cropping the image on the left and right. As you can see, i have set object-fit to "cover".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img.a {
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 70% 70%;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>The object-position Property</h2>

<p>Test to see if object-position is in the middle of the viewport:</p>
<img class="a" src="image_centering.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">

<h2>Original image:</h2>
<img src="image_centering.jpg" width="400px">


</body>
</html>
```

And here's the image i have prepared for you to test it with:
[image: Test Image for Centering object-position]

For me it would be important to find out if this is expected behavior, if i misunderstood something, if it's a bug, if all of you can reproduce this etc.

Edit:
Because people don't seem to understand what i want to achieve, here's a more clear example. On Top you can see the full image we use on desktop, pretty much uncropped because of the aspect ratio. On mobile, bottom picture, if we would just center the image, you can see the watch being cropped off. We want to set a focus point on the watch, so it's in the center of the viewport on mobile.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtT7c.jpg

Edit 2:
This help article by Squarespace may also help identifying my situation. They write quote: "The area set by the focal point now appears as the center of your image".
https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en/articles/205826028-Using-focal-points-to-center-images

Comment: Isn't it easier just to ensure the cross is in the center of your image, and not specify `object-position`?

Comment: No, the test with the cross is just to very specifically test the behavior. We have a website with showcases, and since most pictures are optimized for landscape, we want to keep them on desktop, but usually something in the picture would be important, like a watch, ring, car etc. So for mobile, we want this to be in focus. It looks weird if it is cut off for no reason on the left or right. This comment doesn't really help.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - you want one specified point in the image (in this case the center of the cross??) to be in the center of the viewport and the whole image to be suitably expanded so that it covers the viewport, with cropping as appropriate.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I have added an example in my original post which should explain why i can't just center images for mobile, as it would look bad in some cases.

Comment: *"However it seems that the CSS property object-position doesn't seem to center the set "focal point" of an image in the browser window."* - that's not what object -position does. It sets the position of the image inside the image box IF the dimensions of the image are different from the natural size of the image.

Comment: Yes, but that means basically the same. If the magenta cross is 70% from the left, and i set the object-position to be 70% from the left, it should technically mean that this should be the new orienting point, therefore center of viewport. It also almost works, it's just off by a few percent, and i can't figure out why.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to keep an element (including an image) at the center of the `viewport` at all times, you can simply use `flex` display. See this example below:

```css
div {
width:100vw; /*this makes the parent container fill the entire viewport at all times */
display:flex; /* set flex display */
justify-content:center;align-items:center /* center the child element image */
height:750px; /* just for the demo below not required */
border:4px solid black;
margin:0;
}

body, html {
margin:0;padding:0
}
```

```html
 <div>
 <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/smiley.gif">
 </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't want to keep a full image at the center of the viewport. I want to specify a point of an image that is cropped either on top/bottom or left/right to be in the center of the viewport. The sample above doesn't help, since the image is not "cover".

Comment: I dont understand what you what to achieve sorry. Do you have an online example maybe?

Comment: Here's an example. On the top you can see the picture we use on desktop. If i would just center this image on mobile, you can see what happens in the second image. The watch is cropped of. So the goal is to keep the watch "in focus", so no matter what device/screen size you're on, the watch is always in the center. This is what object-position has been made for: https://imgur.com/a/1l1qonJ

Comment: OK now i understand.